# Is there an rsync-like mode for WinSCP (or a similar tool)?

Tags: backup, sync, rsync, scheduling, winscp

I need to be able to do a periodic sync of content off my Windows 7 x64 laptop to my offsite CentOS 6 webserver.

Is there a tool/mode like rysnc for WinSCP or similar?

For a variety or reasons, Dropbox is not an option here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Synchronize (Ctrl-S):

[image: menu option to synhronize]

The prompts afterwards walk you through what you need to do.

Comment: But does it really use something like rsync to reduce communications traffic?

Comment: @JasonS - don't know how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

There is [cwRsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cwrsync) which I use for backing up data from Windows PCs to Linux servers.

Older versions are [available without fee](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/older-versions-copssh-and-cwrsync-are-available-free)

Answer (score 1):

As per @warren's answer, WinSCP can synchronize files.

If you want to do it periodically, you need to script it (WinSCP supports scripting) and [schedule the WinSCP script using the Windows Scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

Answer (score 0):

The Sync-Option didn't fit my needs.
cwRsync also didn't work for me, gave me an Error on Win7 x64.

I used cygwin's rsync (in a Cygwin-Shell) which worked fine.
http://www.cygwin.com/